# Which edition of SQL Server should be suggested for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: content-delivery, content-manager, broker, database

We are working on one of the RFP (Request for proposal).  As per client's technology stack SQL Server is selected for CMS as well as CDS.

Further client asked us which edition ((express, standard or Professional) of SQL Server 2012 SP2 they should purchase

We dig into www.doc.sdl.com, but did not find edition related information there.  Can anyone help us understanding which edition of SQL Server 2012 SP2 should be suggested for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1.

Comment: You should check the Installation Manual available at (Requires Login): http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?c=t&action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-E55DBE7E-E436-4899-AC75-B412BCC16D69.xml&docid=GUID-E55DBE7E-E436-4899-AC75-B412BCC16D69&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-E55DBE7E-E436-4899-AC75-B412BCC16D69

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you do not have access to the documentations -

For Database recommendation for Content Manager and the Content Delivery is as below:

- Oracle Server 12.1.0.2
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 SP2

Following database can be used and are supported:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 SP2
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3

Following database can also be used but are deprecated:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 SP1
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2

Comment: Thanks Pankaj.  We got this information from www.docs.sdl.com, information we are looking for is which edition (express, standard or Professional) should be recommended for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1

Comment: This is something your business requirement will suggest, you can check MSDN for a similar link for SQL Server 2012 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx
I from my personal experience would recommend using Professional - However, all three are supported I guess.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation you need to refer to is the [Pre-requisites guide](http://sdl.ssl.cdn.sdlmedia.com/file/635543147322472445EY.pdf).

As you have discovered, the documentation does not offer any advice in choosing between the various editions of Microsoft SQL Server. This implies that Tridion does not have any limitation regarding the edition.

Beyond this point, it stops being a Tridion question. You should make reference to the [relevant Microsoft documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/overview.aspx), and make a judgement based on your (potential) customer's requirements and existing infrastructure. That's what they are paying you for, after all.